# Manifest class in build/generated folder disappears

Tags: android, gradle

since a couple of days me and my colleagues couldn't run our apps anymore. At least most of the time. Sometimes it works.

We declare our own permissions in the manifest file and try to access the generated Manifest.java class from our code. This file is being generated when we clean build the app, but disappears when we try to run the app. Which than fails due to the missing file. I found out a way to solve our problem without accessing those permissions in that way, but can somebody explain to me what has changed? We accessed the permissions to send a broadcast. In this case the broadcast was only internal, so we could change that and use [LocalBroadcastManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) instead of [Context.sendBroadcast](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendBroadcast(android.content.Intent,%20java.lang.String)), but what happens if I want to send an exeternal Broadcast and still want to use my own permission...?

Why is the generated Manifest.java class deleted during the run-task? What can I do to prevent it? Or is it wrong to access my permissions in that way and how else can I do that?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is it failing during debug runs? If so, do you have Instant Run enabled? Apart from that, you could always use `PackageManager` to get your app's `PackageInfo`, where the [`permissions` field](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#permissions) will be an array of your defined permissions.

Comment: Hi and thank you. I will try out playing with instant run tomorrow, didn't check that yet. And thanks for the info about permissions in PackageInfo :)

Answer (score 1):

Please manually go to Project location and delete all build folder and Again rebuild and clean project. it will automatically generated

Comment: Yes it is generated, but than deleted again during the run task. That's the problem.